# SpeechKit required condition is false: IsFormatSampleRateAndChannelCountValid(format)

Tags: ios, swift, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

We have implemented SpeechKit for Dictation. Its working fine but sometimes getting crashes from some of users. When the user click to start recording audio engine.

Code:

```
    if recognitionTask != nil {
        recognitionTask?.cancel()
        recognitionTask = nil
    }

    let node = audioEngine.inputNode
    let recordingFormat = node.outputFormat(forBus: 0)
    node.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 1024, format: recordingFormat) { buffer, _ in
        self.request.append(buffer)
    }
    audioEngine.prepare()
    do {
        try audioEngine.start()
    } catch {
        self.sendAlert(message: "There has been an audio engine error.")
        return print(error)
    }

    guard let myRecognizer = SFSpeechRecognizer() else {
        self.sendAlert(message: "Speech recognition is not supported for your current locale.")
        return
    }

    if !myRecognizer.isAvailable {
        self.sendAlert(message: "Speech recognition is not currently available. Check back at a later time.")
        // Recognizer is not available right now
        return
    }

    recognitionTask = speechRecognizer?.recognitionTask(with: request, resultHandler: { result, error in
    //Code here
    })
```

Error:

> Fatal Exception: com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio required condition is
>   false: IsFormatSampleRateAndChannelCountValid(format)

Answer (score 0):

This problem because you may run your project on a virtual machine or any device that doesn't have any mic connected. If you run your project on a real mac device connected with a mic or run it on a real iOS device, you won't face this problem

Comment: Running similar code and not true for me! Worked on sim, but not on device. Still investigating crash :(

Comment: Any reply here on this issue? Still having the same code and the same issue

Comment: This isn't true, I am running this on a device and get this error when I enable dictation:

'com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio', reason: 'required condition is false: IsFormatSampleRateAndChannelCountValid(format)'